# Displaying content of file in tabular format in linux (xargs)

Tags: linux, multiple-columns, xargs

I have a file test.txt with content as:

```
1\1
2
3
4
5\3
6
7
8\66
9
10
11
12
13
14
```

I want to print this file in tabular format having 7 columns like below:

```
1\1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5\3 || 6 || 7
8\66 || 9 || 10 || 11 || 12 || 13 || 14
```

i have tried below cmd in linux:

```
xargs -L 4 < test.txt | awk '$1=$1' OFS=' || '
```

But on running this cmd '\' symbol get removes from the output. It come like this
    11 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 53 || 6 || 7
    866 || 9 || 10 || 11 || 12 || 13 || 14

I don't want \ symbol to be removed. please provide your valuable feedback on this.

Comment: As your original command, i add an option `-d` to xargs, `xargs -L 7 -d '\n' < test.txt | awk '$1=$1' OFS=' || '` can work fine for you.

Comment: Oh yes, It works, Thanks a lots @K.Juce

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -pe 'chomp, $_ .= " || " if $. % 7'
```

`-p` reads the input line by line.

[chomp](http://p3rl.org/chomp) removes the final newline.

`$_ .= ...` appends the given string.

Both chomping and appending only happens if `$.`, the current input line number, is not divisible by 7, i.e. the modulo operator `%` doesn't return 0 for the expression.